# Homestead "The shared folder guest path must be absolute"

Tags: terminal, laravel-5, homestead

I can‘t figure out how to solve this error when I run homestead up:

```
vm:
* The shared folder guest path must be absolute: 

shell provisioner:
* Shell provisioner `args` must be a string or array.
* Shell provisioner `args` must be a string or array.
* Shell provisioner `args` must be a string or array.
```

My homestead.yaml file looks like

```
folders:
- map: ~/Code
to: /home/vagrant/Code/
```

I wrote the same paths like in the laracasts tutorial. What is wrong with the shared folder guest path "/home/vagrant/Code/"?

I have tried a lot of different ways to point to the directory but none of them worked out.

When I echo $PATH in the terminal I get `/Users/username/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin`

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

Change `to: /home/vagrant/Code/` to `to: /home/vagrant/Code`
Also, I think it might have issues with `~/Code` needing to be `/Users/username/Code` instead